# PyQt5 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, gui, qt

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian installed, along with a 7" touch screen.  I'm in the process of creating an application in Python to read several DS18B20 Thermocouples to monitor the temperature of several aquariums (relays attached to heaters will be added later).  I have a form that I created in QT and converted to PyQt5 (through te command line tool) and everything looks the way I want it, except that I can't find the library for PyQT5 for the Raspberry Pi.  How/where can I find this?

Comment: [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=106027) is a related thread. looks old but might still be worth checking out

Comment: *I can't leave a comment, because I don't have enough reputation* I tried what is written above, but the sip file no longer exists, so I can't install sip. Has anyone found the sip file needed for install somewhere else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK... I managed to get this to work.  This is what I did.

1. QT Core needs to be installed with

   sudo apt-get install qt5-default
2. You'll need to copy over [sip](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/4.19/sip-4.19.tar.gz) and [PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) to your Raspberry Pi (I used SFTP). Just put the tar files someplace that you can get to them easily.
3. You'll need to extract each of them, using the tar command, with the -xzvf tag so you'll end up with tar -xzvf sip-4.19.1.tar.gz`for sip.
4. In each folder, you'll need to set up for the build.  This is done by typing "python config.py" in each directory.
5. The contents of each directory needs to be built and installed, go to your sip folder and type "make" this will take a very long time.  After it's through, type "sudo make install".
6. Now do the same thing in your PyQt5 directory.

Comment: Note: It's not quite that simple any longer. The sip configuration now needs to be explicitly told to create PyQt5.sip. See http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/private-sip-td5235854.html

Comment: So, you have to use the tag "--sip-module=PyQt5.sip" on the config line...

Comment: I should point out that I had to use `--sip` tag point to the `sip-4.19.1\sipgen\sip` folder to be able to run the PyQt5 `configure.py`, so I had: `python3 configure.py --sip \home\Downloads\sip-4.19.1\sipgen\sip`

Comment: Another user has pointed out that the link to sip in #2 is dead and recommended this one: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/4.19/sip-4.19.tar.gz Which is a direct tar.gz download. I take no responsibility for it ;)

Answer (score 11):

In Raspbian Stretch Lite the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```

Comment: Oh, good! they've finally added pyqt5 to the repos.

Comment: What should I do after these commands? I still get `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'`

Comment: Is this for python2 or python3?

Answer (score 3):

I developed a similar application using PyQt4 and Qt4-designer. You have to install pyqt4 all modules:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-default qt4-designer qt4-doc qt4-dev-tools python-qt4
```

So in your case just change all 4-5 *i.e qt4 -- qt5*.

Comment: They didn't have the compiled stuff for version 5 in the repository when I wrote this.

Answer (score 3):

*I can't leave a comment, not enough reputation, but thought I should mention this in case it helps anyone using VirtualEnv:*

In my case (Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3, Python 3 in a virtual environment) the answer provided by [CharlieHorse](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/31937/charliehorse) is the only one which worked as I could not get

> sudo apt-get install

to install into virtual environments. I tried something like [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441546/how-i-can-make-apt-get-install-to-my-virtualenv) but because PyQt5 relies on SIP which interfaces with some C code, it needs to be compiled from scratch and can't just be copied, as recommended in the accepted answer of that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try steps mentioned below. It will take some time to make and make install. Please be patient.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default

wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/4.19.24/sip-4.19.24.tar.gz

tar -xzvf sip-4.19.24.tar.gz

cd sip-4.19.24

python configure.py

make

make install
```

---

```
cd ../

wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2008081558.tar.gz

tar -xzvf PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2008081558.tar.gz

cd PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2008081558

python configure.py

make

make install
```

---

```
pip install PyQt5-sip
```