# Installing PyQt5 on raspberry: unable to imoprt PyQt5.sip

Tags: pi-3b+, sip

Trying to install PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi 3B, I followed instructions to first download, extract and install SIP and then download, extract and install PyQt5. 
Python 2.7 and 3.7 are both installed on my pi.

I have installed sip:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/sip-4.19.12 $ python3 configure.py 
This is SIP 4.19.12 for Python 3.7.0 on linux.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/sip-4.19.12 $ make
```

...ran for while, no errors

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/sip-4.19.12 $ make install
```

...ran for while, no errors. 
Then I downloaded and extracted PyQt5 and now my problem is this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/PyQt5_gpl-5.11.2 $ python3 configure.py 
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Error: Unable to import PyQt5.sip. Make sure you have configured SIP to create
a private copy of the sip module.
```

I am stuck now at configuring PyQt5. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why taking so much effort to install *PyQt5* from sources with all its possible errors? It is part of the *Raspbian* repositories. Look what's available with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list *PyQt5*
```

There are also a lot of additional modules. You can simply install *PyQt5* with all needed additional packages:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it installed now. One followup question: in python code "from PyQt5 import QtCore" now results in "No module named 'PyQt5'. How can I make it find that module?

Comment: @TimvanSteenbergen Glad that I could help :-) But I've never used *PyQt5* so I don't know what are its module names to import. Best you ask this in a new question. That's the way this site works.

Comment: Because I am trying to get it working with Python 3.7 and pipenv...

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer provided at [PyQt5 on a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63058/11215) to be "mostly right". However, it's not quite that simple any longer. Following those directions yields

> Error: Unable to import PyQt5.sip. Make sure you have configured SIP
>   to create a private copy of the sip module.

The sip configuration now needs to be explicitly told to create **PyQt5.sip** rather than simply **sip**. See the discussion at http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/private-sip-td5235854.html

What worked for me:

1. Download and unpack the [sip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html) and [PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) sources
2. Then:

   ```
   $ cd <path to sip source>
   $ python3.x configure.py --sip-module=PyQt5.sip
   $ make
   $ sudo make install

   $ cd <path to PyQt5 source>
   $ python3.x configure.py
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   ```