# PYTQ on Rasberry Pi and Friture

Tags: python, boot, version-control

I'm trying to create a stand alone audio analyser using Friture (http://friture.org).

I have a B+ (Rasbian version 9, Python 3 and 2.7. Latest updates.

Trying to install via pip gives me a PYQT find failure_it appears to be looking for v 5.10.1.

I managed to install PYQT v 5.10.1 using this information [PyQt5 on a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/pyqt5-on-a-raspberry-pi)

But I still get the error. I'm wondering if it's a path thing, but I'm not sure how to find out/solve.

I also tried installing Friture from here https://github.com/tlecomte/friture/blob/master/INSTALL.md, but that hangs on pip3.5 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: "*But I still get the error.*" What error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The error is a PYQT find failure—it appears to be looking for v 5.10.1 but, as I said, I apparently have installed it.